# Rendering .ply files in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

So, I'm able to read out the vertices, normals, and indices I need from the .ply file and write them to the VBO. However, I'm not getting the correct shapes. It seems my indices are off.

Here's my structs:

```
typedef struct vtx {
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
} vtx;

typedef struct Face {
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int *vertices;
    float nx, ny, nz;
} Face;

typedef struct PLY_vals {
    Face **f;
    vtx **v;
    unsigned int vcount;
    unsigned int fcount;
    int norms;
    float center[3];
} PLY_vals;
```

Setting up vertices and triangles:

```
nindices = ply.fcount * 3;
nvertices = ply.vcount;
pindices = new GLuint[nindices];
plyverts = new Vertex[nvertices];

for (int i = 0; i < nvertices; i++)
{
    // Vertices
    plyverts[i].location[0] = ply.v[i]->x;
    plyverts[i].location[1] = ply.v[i]->y;
    plyverts[i].location[2] = ply.v[i]->z;
    plyverts[i].location[3] = 1;

    // Normals
    plyverts[i].normal[0] = ply.v[i]->nx;
    plyverts[i].normal[1] = ply.v[i]->ny;
    plyverts[i].normal[2] = ply.v[i]->nz;
    plyverts[i].normal[3] = 0;
}

// set indices (assumes all faces have 3 vertices
int pos=0;
for (int i = 0; i < nindices/3; i++)
{
    pindices[pos++] = ply.f[i]->vertices[0];    // first vertex
    pindices[pos++] = ply.f[i]->vertices[1];    // second vertex
    pindices[pos++] = ply.f[i]->vertices[2];    // third vertex
}
```

This is supposed to be a bunny:

[image]

Any idea? I'm guessing that the vertices are not in the correct order, but I checked and they seem to match up.

Comment: It seems the vertices are correct because it looks like the shape of a bunny, what I think is wrong is the indices as it is making these huge triangles.

Comment: Try rendering the vertices as just points. That will tell you if the vertices are correct or not.

Comment: Does every Face contain 3 vertices?

Comment: Yes, specifically the bunny does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when I used GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT instead of GL_UNSIGNED_INT type specifier for the glDrawElements function. The bunny model (I assume it's the Stanford bunny?) has got over 200000 vertices so the unsigned short is not enough to store the indices since its max value is 65535 - therefore an unsigned int should be used. Maybe that's the answer to your problem?

Comment: This was pretty much it. I was using GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE rather than GL_UNSIGNED_INT. Thanks!